# View XML CDATA from dynamically loaded XML doc

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I have an API that I am working with that allows me to get reports from a server and stores the result in a variable in PHP. My problem is that the data is CDATA encoded so I can't see it when I try to parse through the file. If I download the file and use simplexml_load_file such as:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

It'll work fine, but since the file is loaded through the API, I can't add the LIBXML_NOCDATA option.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(get_report_function(), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Doesn't work, and neither does:

```
$doc = get_report_function();
$xml = simplexml_load_file($doc, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Because it is seen as a SimpleXMLElement object. When I try to:

```
$doc = get_report_function();
file_put_contents($file, $doc, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

It won't allow me to save a SimpleXMLElement to a file. Is there anyway to either apply the LIBXML_NOCDATA option once the document has been loaded or a way to convert a SimpleXMLElement to a format that can be saved to a file?

Answer (score 0):

> or a way to convert a SimpleXMLElement to a format that can be saved to a file

Maybe this one [SimpleXMLElement::asXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)?